# How to apply a value in one row to every row for the account in Dax

Tags: dax, powerbi-desktop

(please reference the picture with sample data)

For an account I'm hoping to take the value in column 'Account Status' and apply the value in the row with the max date that is still less than the date filter. Whatever value is there apply it to every row in the 'Account as of Date' column. For example if the date in the filter was April 23rd 2019 or greater "Inactive" would show for every row of this account for "Account as of Date" and if the date was Oct 19th 2017 to April 22nd 2019 it would show "Active". The date filter is using a date table using a "before" filter so the end user only has one date to deal with.

[sample of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZhAo7.png)

This is my current code for "Status as of Date". In the picture it currently just repeats what's given.

```
    STATUS AS OF DATE = 

var maxDate = CALCULATE(MAX('MASTER CHARGE ACTIONS'[CHG_DATE]), FILTER('MASTER CHARGE ACTIONS', 'MASTER CHARGE ACTIONS'[CHG_DATE] <= MAX('Date Table'[Date])),ALLEXCEPT('MASTER CHARGE ACTIONS','MASTER CHARGE ACTIONS'[BI_ACCT]))

RETURN CALCULATE(FIRSTNONBLANK('MASTER CHARGE ACTIONS'[Account Status],1),ALLEXCEPT('MASTER CHARGE ACTIONS','MASTER CHARGE ACTIONS'[BI_ACCT],'MASTER CHARGE ACTIONS'[BI_CHG_CD],'MASTER CHARGE ACTIONS'[Account Status]),'MASTER CHARGE ACTIONS'[CHG_DATE] = maxDate)
```

If any additional information is needed please let me know. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

When you get a maxDate with the expression:

```
MAX('Date Table'[Date])
```

It will be always = 5/19/2022, because the 'Date Table' is limited only by the slicer.
I've refactored your code, so you it will let you compare with a new version.

```
CALCULATE(
    MAX('MASTER CHARGE ACTIONS'[CHG_DATE])
    , FILTER(
        'MASTER CHARGE ACTIONS'
        ,'MASTER CHARGE ACTIONS'[CHG_DATE] <= MAX('Date Table'[Date])
    )
    ,ALLEXCEPT('MASTER CHARGE ACTIONS','MASTER CHARGE ACTIONS'[BI_ACCT])
)
Return
CALCULATE(
     FIRSTNONBLANK('MASTER CHARGE ACTIONS'[Account Status],1)
     ,ALLEXCEPT(
            'MASTER CHARGE ACTIONS'
            ,'MASTER CHARGE ACTIONS'[BI_ACCT]
            ,'MASTER CHARGE ACTIONS'[BI_CHG_CD]
            ,'MASTER CHARGE ACTIONS'[Account Status]
     )
     ,'MASTER CHARGE ACTIONS'[CHG_DATE] = maxDate
)
```

According to the DAX priorities ALLEXCEPT works first, then FILTER, then calculating MAX. So, first, you are opening the table with ALLEXCEPT and then you are reducing the 'MASTER CHARGE ACTIONS' with the Filter, but in fact - not. In your sample MAX('Date Table'[Date]) gives 5/19/2022 always.

Try something like:

```
TEST 3 = 
VAR tDate= MAX('Date Table'[Date])
VAR maxDate = 
    Calculate(
        MAX('MASTER CHARGE ACTIONS'[CHG_DATE])
        ,'MASTER CHARGE ACTIONS'[CHG_DATE]<=tDate
        ,ALLEXCEPT(
                 'MASTER CHARGE ACTIONS'
                 ,'MASTER CHARGE ACTIONS'[BI_ACCT]
        )
    )
VAR Stts = 
    Calculate(
        LASTNONBLANK(
                   'MASTER CHARGE ACTIONS'[Account Status]
                   ,Countrows('MASTER CHARGE ACTIONS')=1
        )
        ,ALLEXCEPT(
                  'MASTER CHARGE ACTIONS'
                  ,'MASTER CHARGE ACTIONS'[BI_ACCT]
        )
        ,'MASTER CHARGE ACTIONS'[CHG_DATE]=maxDate
    )
VAR Result=Stts

RETURN Result
```

Not sure this will works, but let me know if it will ).

Comment: Thanks for the reply Mik.

I tried a simple copy and paste of the last bit of code you provided and unfortunately it repeats the first value for all rows of the account. When I uncomment the account status portion only may rows for April 5th, 2019 have values and they show "active". Would this solution still adapt to the date table? I just want to make sure the end user still have functionality

Here is a link to the test file if you would be open to taking another look. Thank you again!
https://www.dropbox.com/s/6kb5j8vblv4n2po/OZARKSGO%202.1.pbix?dl=0

Comment: Hi again. Try then this one. I edited the code in the answer.